# Spark - explode and merge columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have data for processing in PySpark SQL that looks like this:

```
+---------+----------------+
|user_id  |user_ids        |
+---------+----------------+
|null     |[479534, 1234]  |
|null     |[1234]          |
|null     |[479535]        |
|null     |[479535, 479536]|
|null     |[1234]          |
|null     |[479535]        |
|1234567  |null            |
|1234567  |null            |
|777      |null            |
|888      |null            |
|null     |null            |
+---------+----------------+
```

I need just a single `user_id` column, with additional rows exploded from `user_ids`, so something like this:

```
+---------+
|user_id  |
+---------+
|479534   |
|1234     |
|1234     |
|479535   |
|479535   |
|479536   |
|1234     |
|479535   |
|1234567  |
|1234567  |
|777      |
|888      |
|null     |
+---------+
```

How can I achieve that?

I've tried:

```
    .withColumn("user_ids", F.explode_outer("user_ids"))
    .withColumn("user_id", F.coalesce(df["user_id"], df["user_ids"]))
```

But with that I get:

```
cannot resolve 'coalesce(user_id, user_ids)' due to data type mismatch: input to function coalesce should all be the same type, but it's [bigint, array<bigint>];
```

So I think that `withColumn` cannot use another created column in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not saving the dataframe after the explode, so do not refer the columns as `df['col']` but just call `F.col('col')`. For example,

```
df.withColumn('user_ids', F.explode_outer('user_ids'))
  .withColumn('user_id',  F.coalesce(F.col('user_id'), F.col('user_ids')))
```

---

Here is my trial.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as f


df = spark.createDataFrame([[None, [479534, 1234]], [1234567, None]], ['user_id', 'user_ids'])
df.show()

+-------+--------------+
|user_id|      user_ids|
+-------+--------------+
|   null|[479534, 1234]|
|1234567|          null|
+-------+--------------+

df.withColumn('user_ids', f.explode_outer('user_ids')) \
  .withColumn('user_id',  f.coalesce(f.col('user_id'), f.col('user_ids'))) \
  .drop('user_ids') \
  .show()

+-------+
|user_id|
+-------+
| 479534|
|   1234|
|1234567|
+-------+
```